# How to change a Windows username using the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm a Windows 7 user i used to change the username from the control panel. But I would like to know how to change it using the CLI not the GUI I have searched alot but didn't find the answer or it was unclear. A simple explanation to the code would be great

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use wmic for this. The command is:

```
wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename newname
```

Example, if your username is "user" and you want to rename to "person" the following command would be used.

```
wmic useraccount where name='user' rename person
```

Please note, you need administrative privileges to use this command, so make sure you start your command prompt using `run as administrator`.

EDIT: suddenly you mention in the comments that you do NOT want to change the Username, but the Full Name instead.

The command for that is here:

```
wmic useraccount where fullname='currentname' rename newname
```

You can substitute fullname or name for any of the following:

```
AccountType  Description  Disabled  Domain    FullName     InstallDate  LocalAccount  Lockout  Name   PasswordChangeable  PasswordExpires  PasswordRequired  SID  SIDType  Status
```

You can use the following command to see a list of all users with all their settings:

```
wmic useraccount list
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I found this site too https://www.windows-commandline.com/wmic-useraccounts/

Comment: Please accept so others know you no longer require any help. And yes, this was literally the first site google found for me. Others would've voted your answer down for not taking any effort in searching.

Comment: but i need to change the full name not the name

Comment: Your question says how to change windows user name. If you now suddenly talk about the full name, then you have to specify your question better.

Comment: This also works on Windows 10 Home edition (and it's the only way to do so, as Computer Management does not allow to change users names).

Comment: [@LPChip's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1159931/453834) works great on Windows 10 Pro (and as [@gaborous mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1159929/how-to-change-windows-user-name-in-cmd/1159931#comment2102768_1159931), it was the only way I could find to fully change the username in Windows 10). However, **I had to restart my computer** in order for the new username to take effect.

Comment: If I execute the command `wmic useraccount list`, it shows the new username, but this does not change, for example, the names of the folders that were previously referenced with the old username, i.e. inside `C:\Users` I still have the folder with the old username. I want to change everything that previously used the old username (which I didn't even choose) to use this new username. Is there a way to change that too?

Comment: @nbro create a new user and migrate everything over. There's no simple command to do what you ask.

Comment: @LPChip So, why would one even want to do what you suggest in this answer?

Comment: You can manually change things, its just not a one-command job as you request.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do what you want:

```
net user JDoe /fullname:"John Doe"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `wmic` solution didn't work for me, and apparently [WMIC is now deprecated as of Windows 10 21H1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features). The following worked for me in an elevated PowerShell, however:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "name='oldname'").Rename("newname")
```

[This is also deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi), apparently, but at least it works. I couldn't figure out the newer CIM methods without getting some sort of `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.` error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `wmic` doesn't take effect, after lots of search, finally I find create another account and delete current account works.

Go to `Control Panel > User Accounts`, create a new account with new user name, and set it to Administrator. Then log out, and log in with new account, then delete the old account, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using powershell, you can also use the cmdlet [**`Rename-LocalUser`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/rename-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) like this:

```
Rename-LocalUser -Name "Kylem" -NewName "kylemit"
```