# Unable to change user name on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I want to change the command prompt user name being displayed to `bilesh` instead of `biles`

[image]

I used the following command.

```
wmic useraccount where name='biles' rename name bilesh
```

Which was successful. Then, I restarted the machine. But the folder name was not updated.

Any way I can do this without breaking anything?

Comment: User folder cannot be changed due to its integration onto the registry, everything else can, log in etc...All you can do to get a new user account folder name is create a new user account and migrate the old account to the new one.

Comment: Also, your syntax in command prompt is wrong. See this answer on what it is supposed to be: https://superuser.com/questions/1159929/how-to-change-windows-user-name-in-cmd/1159931#1159931

Comment: @Moab the wmic command should change the registry items too.

Comment: @LPChip I did fire the correct command... Just wrote it wrong here... Sorry for that...