# Why is the name in cmd path not changing in windows 11?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, microsoft-account

I have just bought a new laptop and installed windows 11 on it, my username was called 'eigenaar' at the beginning, which is 'owner' in my native language. So I changed that in the control panel >> user account settings to MSM. Now I have this:

[image]

Now when I opened my cmd the path looks like this:

[image]

My desired output was that my path in cmd should have looked like this: C:\Users\MSM>

I googled around but could not get it solved, hope you guys can help me.

Comment: The change you made did not change the user profile name so that is what Windows used. This is the same in Windows 11 and in Windows 10.

Comment: @John I know that but now the question is how can I solve my issue?

Comment: Try this tutorial and see if it works. I do not change these.  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89060-change-name-user-profile-folder-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a Windows username using the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/1159929/how-to-change-a-windows-username-using-the-command-prompt) (you changed the displayname instead of the username)

Answer (score 0):

Two more places to change:

- Rename your folder in `C:\Users` to `MSM`
- Use `regedit` to navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`,
  identify your account by the value of `ProfileImagePath`
  and change it to `C:\Users\MSM`

Reboot after this change.

Ensure that you have another usable administrator
account, in case something goes wrong and you can't login
after this change.

Comment: when I navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` I only see `Default, Default ProfilesDirectory, ProgramData, Public`. I also tried your first option but I cannot change the folders name

Comment: Look inside the sub-folders. It will look similar to `S-1-5-21-495099530-557473056-3318008218-1001`.