# How to change User folder name

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Hi I just refreshed my W10 with a clean install and I made some changes from my last windows install

On my last pc I had my Users in `C:\Users` and I changed my Picture, Downloads and all the user's folders inside `E:\Gabriel` to save space on my C drive

Then I changed my User folders from `C:\Users` to `E:\Users\` so when I used my email to create a User on my fresh Windows 10 it created the User Grez_ and I would like to change it to Gabriel

I used this [tuto](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html) to change my User folder location so I dont have to lose my apps settings or other thing when I decide to refresh my windows installation.

Is there a way to rename the `E:/User/Grez_` to `E:/User/Gabriel`

I tried this [tuto](https://www.lifewire.com/change-user-folder-name-in-windows-10-5114140) but when I do `Rename Grez_ Gabriel` I get an Access Denied and if I just create a folder `E:/User/Gabriel` and then change the `ProfileImagePath` in regedit then reboot the PC cant find my profile and logs me with a temp profile

I also tried to change the Windows Username with [this](https://superuser.com/a/1159931/1156374) but when I try to open, save, delete files inside the `E:\Users\Grez_\any_folder` I get `no mapping between account names and security ids was done` error

Comment: It is just plain easier and simpler to use the profile name Windows uses.  It is possible to change but not worth the effort

Comment: what if I want to do the effort ?

Comment: I tried changing the name and it did not work for me and so I left it